# Errors in stat_smooth line fit for some groups cause no plot to be produced

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot curves for a data set with a large number of  different groups.  I want to visualize the curves all together on one  graph fit to a common model (stat_smooth with a glm with a  quasipoisson error), so, I'm using color to group them.  However, for some curves, the fitting function borks out and I get

Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values

And then there is no plot.

Is there a way to have the plot come up without the curves for those "bad" groups?  I ask as there are a huge number of groups, and while I could write an error-check script to then kick them out of the data, it would be nicer if everything but those with an error would plot.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the plot code in a `try` statement?

Comment: I agree with @BenBolker; the "right" way to do this is to do the model fitting outside of `ggplot` using `try`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a *very* easy way to do this, but here's what I would try:

Write a loop or an `ldply` statement to run the model you have in mind, wrapped in `try`: e.g.

```
trymodelList <- ldply(mydata,.(grp1,grp2),glm,formula=y~x,family="quasipoisson")
```

(I think that the current data chunk should get filled in automatically as the `data` argument).

Figure out which ones were bad: something like `alply(trymodelList,inherits,what="try-error")`

Use this logical vector to subset out the groups you don't want, then pass the subsetted data to `geom_smooth` instead of the full data set.

I know there are a few details left out ...

**edit**: I see that I've essentially written down your "write an error-check script ... then kick them out of the data" strategy.  Sorry, I don't think there's an easier way to do this.  You might try the ggplot users' list ...

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to avoid that, as it's not quite as general of a solution.  Hrm.  Thanks, though!

Comment: @Ben. Two suggestions. One, I think you meant `dlply` since input is a `data.frame` and the output is a `list` of models.Two, you can wrap the call to `glm` as `failwith('error', glm)` which automatically returns an error.